# How to read hidden form data in Flask function

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am working on an assignment for a Flask application with a function that does different things based on the value of a hidden field in a form on the index.html page. I am to have only two routes: '/' (index.html) and '/process' (which performs actions on index.html).

When I run this in Flask (python server.py in a virtualenv), and click the button "Make Money" on index.html, I get this error:

"TypeError
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable"

Can someone please tell me how I can get the desired value from the hidden input?

contents of server.py

```
import datetime
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'fooBarBaz'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['GET','POST'])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        target = request.form('name')
        if target == 'clothing':
            new_money = random.randrange(10, 21)
            session['balance'] += new_money
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            session['register'] += ("Received" + new_money + " dollars at " + timestamp.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M %p")) 
        return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

contents of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div container>
        <div class='balance'>
            <p>Your balance:  {{ session['balance'] }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="shops">
            <div class="clothing">
                <h2>Clothing Store</h2>
                <p>(earns 10 - 20 dollars)</p>
                <form action="/process" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="clothing">
                    <input type="submit" value="Make Money!">
                </form>
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="register">
            <h4>Receipt Tape</h4>
            <p>{{ session['register'] }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `target = request.form('name')` cannot work, just use brackets instead. but you don't have any input named `"name"`, should it be `clothing` maybe ?

Comment: btw, you may facing another issue with `session['balance'] += new_money`, if `session['balance']` is not declared before, you cannot use this operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form should be something like below, with a value defined for the hidden input:

```
<form action="/process" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="clothing" value="clothing">
    <input type="submit" value="Make Money!">
</form>
```

Without changing the logic too much, the register section could accept html tags to render linebreaks

```
<p>{{ session['register']|safe }}</p>
```

Then with minimal changes, this is how you could resolve some issues you are facing in the view. To avoid error about `session` key not declared, the best way is to used the method `get` with `0`, or `""` instead of the `None` returned when the key is not found:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['GET','POST'])
def process():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        target = request.form.get('clothing')
        if target == 'clothing':
            new_money = random.randrange(10, 21)
            session['balance'] = session.get('balance',0) + new_money
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            session['register'] = "{}<br>Received {} dollars at {}".format(
                session.get('register',''),
                new_money,
                timestamp.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M %p"))
        return render_template('index.html')
```